# Знаки вопроса вместо русских символов в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, кодировка

Перезапустил *Android Studio* и все мои коментарии превратились в знаки вопроса `?` Кодировка была *windows-1251*, переделал в *UTF-8* - та же проблема.

Как решить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эх, надо было писать комментарии на английском...

Comment: [Вот это](https://praveenboyalapalli.wordpress.com/2015/01/29/unmappable-character-for-encoding-utf-8-in-android-studio-1-0-2/) подойдет для восстановления комментов (вариант Reload)? Если нет, попробуйте открыть файл в блокноте, если опяить нет, поищите в "предыдущих версиях", если они включены. Если нечем будет восстановить, сохраняете файл как UTF8 и перенабираете все комментарии. :(

Comment: Каким боком тут Eclipse?

Comment: думаю тут notepad++ поможет. Нужно открыть файли и перекодировать на utf-8, должно сработать